# Pandas pulling out rows using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is ~50,000 rows long and am trying to pull out  a subset of rows based on a list. I have confirmed my list `c` has all the right id names of rows I want to exract and that all these ids are in my original dataframe, but when I use loc to extract the rows into a new dataframe it is only pulling out about half of the ids I identify in list c. The loc function in pandas is working great on smaller tests but I can't figure out why it wouldn't work on my larger dataframe. Could it be because my index has both numerical and string based values?

Any ideas of why this could be happening or alternatives to the loc function to do this?

This is my code:

```
c = ['a','b','f','h','y']

df = pd.read_table('count_table.txt',comment="#",index_col='id')

df2 =df.loc[df.index.isin(c)]
```

For added information my actual dataframe looks like this:

```
            T1   T2   T3
   A1       1     +   89 
   A2       2     +   12
   A3       3     +    0
   4        4     +   11
   5        5     -    7
   6        6     -    8
   7        7     +   56
   8        8     -   21
   MS1      1     +    1
   MS2      2     +    8
   NH5      5     +    0
   NH7      7     +   12
   .....
```

The expected output would be a new dataframe that has only the rows with indexes in list c.

So lets say I had the dataframe above and a a list `c=['MS1','NH5','8','4','5']`  I want a dataframe that looks like:

```
            T1   T2   T3
   4        4     +   11
   5        5     -    7
   8        8     -   21
   MS1      1     +    1
   NH5      5     +    0
```

What I am getting instead is something like this where it is missing some of the values clearly in list `c`:

```
            T1   T2   T3
   4        4     +   11
   8        8     -   21
   NH5      5     +    0
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I updated the question to give a more clear idea. I want to get a new dataframe only with selected rows based on a list of indexes I already have.

Comment: you may have white space in index

Comment: Have you checked all your indices are strings?

Comment: I haven't but I will check for white spaces and confirm all my indixes are strings. I had initially figured that since some of the indexes were strings pandas would assume all of them were.

Comment: You called it with the white space. Not sure how only half ended up with extra white space but it appears that was where this issue was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `isin` to get mask:

```
c=['MS1','NH5',8,4,5]
subset_df=df[df.index.isin(c)]
```

note `8`,`4`,`5` type in index.